# Intercept calls to folder on ubuntu and emulate folder behaviour

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-s3, filesystems

I have a big CRM system on PHP, which active works with users files, and stores them in the folder in the root of the project. Now i need to change system to save files on Amazon S3, but because of bad arhitecture of the system (it's an old open-source system) i cannot just rewrite the code. So, i got a little bit crazy idea, to intercept all system calls to one folder ("/var/www/%my_project%/uploads"), and process them in special way. PHP should be sure that it works with usual folder, file_put_contents and file_get_contents should work as usual, but in fact they should work with code which will serve files from S3 for them. Is that possible (how?), or it's too crazy idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: S3 stream wrapper, as long as you prefix the filepaths with `s3://` or use something like fuse to mount that folder as an s3 folder

Comment: Hmm, thanks a lot! I don't know why i didn't found this solution by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html) helped me. It's needed just to create a client object, and call registerStreamWrapper method. That's all, now you can work with a folder "s3://yourbacketname" as with usual folder.